# how to fix jquery ajax data shows [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

For example i have NAME stored in my database, and the result  is [object Object]

```js
var data= {};

.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 contentType: 'application/json',
 url: 'http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/surveyform/form45/post',      
    
  success: function(data) {
              $('#NAME').val(data.NAME);  
    }
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `data.NAME` is not an object?

Comment: Try `console.log`-ing your variable to explore its contents.

Comment: What do you mean by its not an object @VsevolodGoloviznin

yes i tried console.log it, but the result is [object Object], and tried console.log(data.NAME) and resulted my wanted answer at Philip

Comment: That's because your `data.NAME` is not a string, but an object. You can stringify it and see the content: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.NAME))`

Comment: already used stringify at the start of the ajax, and i tried your suggestion and resulted to [object Object] again @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: add `dataType:'json'` in your `$.ajax` call. e.g `type:'POST',dataType:'json',......`

Comment: It doesnt work @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: `contentType` is the type of data you're sending.`dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server e.g `json`, `html`, `text`, etc. so I think if you send your response in `json` format from server then I believed that you can get your data by `console.log(data['NAME']);`

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez did it solve your problem?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna i already solved the problem, my code above is working, the error is on other functions. sorry for the inconvinience. Thanks very much